# javascript null value not working

Tags: javascript, asp.net, null

here's my function for checking zipcode. When a null values comes in, i keep getting "Object Required" Does anyone know where im going wrong?

aspx tags -

```
asp:CustomValidator 
    ID="cv_zipcode" 
    runat="server"      
    ControlToValidate="tb_zipcode"
    ClientValidationFunction="ValidateZipcode" 
    ValidateEmptyText="true" 
    Display="Dynamic" 
    ValidationGroup="vgroup">
</asp:CustomValidator>
```

```
function ValidateZipcode(sender, args) {
              var regZipcode = '\d{5}'
        var zipcode = document.getElementById(sender.id.replace(/cv_/, "tb_"));
                    if ((zipcode.value == "ZipCode") || (zipcode.value.length == null) || (zipcode.value.length == "")) {
            zipcode.style.backgroundColor = "#f6e086";
            args.IsValid = false; return;
        } else {
            args.IsValid = true;
            zipcode.style.backgroundColor = "white";
        }
    }
```

Comment: You get errors when what is null? zipcode?

Comment: Can you get your element by its typed id (tb_zipcode), rather than replacing text on the sender id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly which value is null, but in general, if you have a variable x which may or may not be null, and you want to do something with x, you can do the following:

```
x != null && do_something_with(x)
```

If `x == null`, then this returns false and doesn't try to execute `do_something_with()`. Otherwise, this expression returns the value of `do_something_with(x)`.

If you just `do_something_with(x)`, and x is null, and `do_something_with()` is not expecting a null, you can get errors.

**EDIT:**

try:

```
if ((zipcode == null) || (zipcode.value == null) || [everything else])
```

Answer (score 0):

zipcode.value.length returns an integer

I think you should have

```
if ((zipcode.value == "ZipCode") || (zipcode.value.length == 0))
```

Answer (score 0):

I would be a little suspect of this line:

```
if ((zipcode.value == "ZipCode") || (zipcode.value.length == null) || (zipcode.value.length == "")) {
```

Try this instead:

```
if ((zipCode.value == null) || (zipcode.value== "") || (zipcode.value.length == 0)) {
```

Comment: `zipcode.value.length` will never return null. `zipcode` or `zipcode.value` might, but `length` is an int.

Answer (score 0):

That error message usually indicates that you've tried to get or set a property or call a method of something that isn't an object, which tends to happen when a variable that you thought referred to an object is actuall null or undefined. That is, if `someVariable` is null or undefined then you can't say `someVariable.someProperty`.

If `.getElementById()` doesn't find a matching element it returns null, so in this line:

```
var zipcode = document.getElementById(sender.id.replace(/cv_/, "tb_"));
```

`zipcode` is potentially set to null, and if it is then all attempts to access properties of `zipcode` like `zipcode.value` and `zipcode.style` will fail.

If the parameter `args` comes in as null or undefined then attempting to set `args.IsValid` will fail, and similarly if the parameter `sender` is null or undefined then `sender.id` will fail.

So, if you have a variable that might be null you should test that before trying to do anything else with it.